# Arrow key selection does not work to Autocompleated combo box when combo box values are reload java Fx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, autocomplete, controlsfx

The 1st time program is loaded the arrow key selection in autocomplete combobox  works. But after I clear and reload the values in it using a method below the arrow key navigation and selection of combobox items does not work.
I use [TextFields.bindAutoCompletion](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.html) method from ControlsFx 8 to bind combobox.

```
// load Auto Compleat nic,fname,lname,id values for search Combo Box
private void loadValuesToComboSearchBox() {
    try {
        // clear elements of Search Combo Box
        comboSearch.getItems().clear();

        // Disable Search Combo Box
        comboSearch.setEditable(false);

        // load Auto Compleat nic,fname,lname,id values for search Text Field
        ResultSet getsearchElements = employeDao.getSearchemployeeByNicFnameLnmeId();
        LinkedHashSet<String> addElements = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        while (getsearchElements.next()) {
            addElements.add(getsearchElements.getString("id"));
            addElements.add(getsearchElements.getString("firstname"));
            addElements.add(getsearchElements.getString("lastname"));
            addElements.add(getsearchElements.getString("nic"));
        }

        // Add elements to Auto Compleat Text Field
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboSearch.getEditor(), addElements);

        // Enable Search Combo Box
        comboSearch.setEditable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, e + "", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue occurs due to the several overlapping `AutoCompletionBinding`s.
In order to fix that you should keep reference to the previous binding and dispose it upon reload. Also, note that to clear the selection in JavaFX combobox more steps should be performed.

```
private AutoCompletionBinding<String> completion;
....
private void loadValuesToComboSearchBox() {
    try {
        // clear selection
        comboSearch.getItems().clear();
        comboSearch.valueProperty().set(null);
        comboSearch.getEditor().clear();

        comboSearch.setEditable(false);
        ResultSet getSearchElements = employeDao.getSearchemployeeByNicFnameLnmeId();
        Set<String> addElements = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        while (getSearchElements.next()) {
            addElements.add(getSearchElements.getString("id"));
            addElements.add(getSearchElements.getString("firstname"));
            addElements.add(getSearchElements.getString("lastname"));
            addElements.add(getSearchElements.getString("nic"));
        }

        if (completion != null) {
            completion.dispose();
        }
        completion = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboSearch.getEditor(), addElements);
        comboSearch.setEditable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, e + "", ButtonType.OK).showAndWait();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```